# How do I fix the mission bug in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

I recently bought the Borderlands GOTY edition when they announced the pre-release of BL2, and while playing through it, I'm stuck on a quest, "Keeping Your Insides Inside"

In the mission, you are supposed to buy a shield, but the thing is, I've already completed it before, and for some reason, I can't complete the mission, talking to Zed doesn't work and anything else doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: I am a little confused. Is the bug the fact that the game allowed you to pick up a quest a second time after you completed it?

Comment: This quest popped up again for me after I went online once and wouldn't go away. I was able to just ignore it and carry on with other quests, can you do this?

Comment: Try purchasing a second shield and equipping it

Comment: You are able to complete the game with a bunch of sidequests that are still lingering that have not been completed. The main storyline quests will need to be completed, of course, but sidequests are there just fro extra EXP and money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This quest is a quest that would not normally be assigned. The reason this quest popped up for you after playing online is that whoever hosted the game had modded their save file to make them have that quest, and because you joined them, it was passed on to you. There is no way to complete it in game, so you'll have to use [WillowTree](http://sourceforge.net/projects/willowtree/) (a Borderlands modding tool) to mark the quest as completed.

Download it from that link, unzip it, and run the exe. Click the willow tree icon in the top left and select Open. Go to your saved games (Documents/My Games/Borderlands/savedata) and select the right save. If you don't know which one it is, no worries, just open one of them and go to the General Info tab in WillowTree to see if that's the right one.

Once you've opened the right save, go to the Quests tab, expand Playthrough 2 Quests, and select Keeping Your Insides Inside. Open the Progress dropdown, and select Finished. Then click the WillowTree icon again, hit save, and load up your character in game. You should no longer have to worry about trying to finish that quest.

Comment: perfect! it worked like a charm

Comment: Good! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The web app, **[Willow Shrubbery](http://www.myborderlands.com/Default.aspx)**, has a feature that removes glitched/viral quests, [including the "Keep Your Insides Inside" quest](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=114222), by fixing the save file with the glitched/viral quest(s).

[image: Willow Shrubbery]